# Start execution if it is not in progress yet, otherwise wait for the existing execution to finish in concurrent Java method call

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, synchronization, java.util.concurrent

Imagine I have a class whose method (`process`) can be called concurrently.
This method does some processing (`doProcess`) that cannot be executed concurrently. Moreover, if `process` method was called, but processing (`doProcess`) is already in progress - invocation of `process` should wait until the already started processing (`doProcess`) is finished and then return (without starting new processing - `doProcess`). Calling `process` method will only do actual processing (`doProcess`) if none of threads is doing actual processing (`doProcess`) yet.

```kotlin
// Just imaginary example to illustrate the idea
class MyResource() {
   val lock = MyLock()
   fun process() {
      if (!lock.isLocked) {
         lock.lock()
         doProcess()
         lock.unlock()
      }
      lock.awaitUnlocked()
   }
   private fun doProcess() {
      // actual processing
   }
}
```

What would be the intended concurrency (java.util.concurrent) primitive for the concurrency problem described in the imaginary example above? I thought about `ReentrantLock` but it does not offer `awaitUnlocked`. And the `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` seems too low-level for this simple use case.

Comment: The design seems a bit confusing. Why would the thread block and then end up doing nothing? What does the thread do the rest of the time when it's not either processing or waiting for another thread doing processing? Please use a real example, not an imaginary one. Otherwise you can use for example `Future` to wait for the result of a calculation.

Comment: @Kayaman more real-world example would be (re)establishing some connection. For instance: you are downloading some resources. Each task means downloading a single resource. Many tasks running concurrently means dowloading a bunch of resources. In some point of the time you loose the connection. Each of your concurrent tasks notices it and tries to reastablish the connection via blocking function call. However, if reconnecting is in progress, each of your concurrent tasks should not restart the reconnecting process, but wait for it to be finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are after could be accomplished with a ConcurrentMap - more specifically, computeIfAbsent.

For instance, you can run the code below. Works a bit like a cache - if you what you want is available, simply return it. Otherwise wait for which ever thread gets there first to compute it first.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ConcurrencyTest
{
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, String> processItems = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public String process()
    {
        return processItems.computeIfAbsent("doProcess", k -> doProcess());
    }

    private String doProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(Instant.now() + " -> doProcess() Starting some work on " + Thread.currentThread());
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(Instant.now() + " -> doProcess() Finished some work on " + Thread.currentThread());
            return Instant.now().toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected Exception : " + e, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * And to test it out.
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        final int THREADS = 10;
        final ConcurrencyTest test = new ConcurrencyTest();
        final ExecutorService execs = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);
        final CountDownLatch startingGun = new CountDownLatch(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        {
            execs.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println(Instant.now() + " -> Thread -> " + Thread.currentThread() + " - Awaiting Starting Gun");
                try
                {
                    startingGun.await();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failure waiting for the starting gun.");
                }
                System.out.println(Instant.now() + " -> Running Thread -> " + Thread.currentThread());
                String val = test.process();
                System.out.println(Instant.now() + " -> Got back " + val + " -> " + Thread.currentThread());
            });
        }

        System.out.println("All tasks submitted.. waiting for 5 seconds then firing the starting gun. ");
        Thread.sleep(5_000);
        startingGun.countDown();
        execs.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Gets me the output below. As you can see only one thread end up executing the code in question. The rest wait on it.

```
All tasks submitted.. waiting for 5 seconds then firing the starting gun. 
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696626Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696606Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696245Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696231Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696627Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696633Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696274Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696231Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696620Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:51.696261Z -> Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main] - Awaiting Starting Gun
2021-12-30T17:59:56.695927Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.696031Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.695968Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.695863Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.695832Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.696063Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.696133Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.696254Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.696230Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.696204Z -> Running Thread -> Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.714154Z -> doProcess() Starting some work on Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.814608Z -> doProcess() Finished some work on Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815375Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815422Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815104Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815065Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815093Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815054Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815420Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815387Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815077Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main]
2021-12-30T17:59:56.815435Z -> Got back 2021-12-30T17:59:56.815016Z -> Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main]
```